# Writing to external storage

Tags: android, robotium

I am automating an apk, whose source code is not accessible to me (actually I am not authorized to change it). Now when I run the test and write logs on the sdcard, it gives me permission denied. Giving WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest of my test application doesn't have any effect. 
But if I put permission in the app under test then I get write permission to write on the sdcard.
My question, is it necessary to have permission in the app under test (not the test application). If possible, do I need to do something special to give permission through my test application without modifying the manifest of application under test?

Answer (score 1):

as for now it is not possible because robotium drives the actual apk so any permission required is supposed to be provided to the application under test. i am also trying to create bridge through which we can get logs without needing to edit the app under test.